# POST JSON with python and reading response

Tags: python, json, urllib2, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request in python and I believe I am doing everything correct. However it is not returning any response. I can't seem to figure out if there is anything wrong with my request. It seems like there may be something wrong with the service if I am not getting any response back. Is there anything inherently wrong with what I've written here?

```
import json
import urllib2

data = {'first_name': 'John','last_name': 'Smith','email': 'johnsmith@smith.com','phone': '215-555-1212'}

req = urllib2.Request('https://someurl.io/')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
print response.read()
print response.headers
```

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but using `urllib2` is a pain. Try [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I think you'll like it. It's generally a much simpler API. Eliminates a lot of boiler plate. Even has a nice [`post`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=post#requests.post) method.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, unless you love urllib2, I suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Here's the same data code in requests:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'first_name': 'John','last_name': 'Smith','email': 'johnsmith@smith.com','phone': '215-555-1212'}
url = 'https://someurl.io/'

r = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(payload))

print r.content
print r.headers
```